# Can't align quote to middle

Tags: css

I am trying to vertically align to the middle at all times an open quote by a pseudo element. As you shrink the size it aligns, but by default it's above my quote. Is there a way I can have it vertically in the middle aligned at all times?

**CSS**

```
blockquote {
    margin: 3em;
    padding: 0 3em;
    position: relative;
}

blockquote::before {
    content: open-quote;
    left: -40px;
}


blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
    top: 50%;
    color: #F1722E;
    font-size: 124px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<blockquote>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus iure rem repudiandae incidunt corporis obcaecati voluptate officia. Facere laborum ipsam molestiae dolorum libero nesciunt ducimus aliquid voluptatibus. Ad praesentium fugiat.</blockquote>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gfybkpc9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by adjusting the margin top of the open quote. See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gfybkpc9/1/)

I adjusted the CSS like so:

```
blockquote {
    margin: 3em;
    padding: 0 3em;
    position: relative;
}

blockquote::before {
    content:'"';
    left: -40px;
}


blockquote::before, blockquote::after {
    top: 50%;
    color: #F1722E;
    font-size: 124px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top:-48px;
}
```

Essentially, the margin top would be half the height of the element, which would position the middle of the element at 50%, per the `top` property. Since it's a quote mark, we have to fudge the numbers a little.